# Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 156179 > 65536) on Dialogflow SDK

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

I'm following a 2018 tutorial on how to implement dialogflow on android app. But then when I follow that tutorial, I stumble upon a problem when putting the dependencies.

This is what my build.gradle file looks like

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.specialgift"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'


    implementation 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7@aar'
    implementation 'ai.api:libai:1.6.12'

    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.67.0-alpha'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.15.1'


}
```

I got an error message saying

**Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 156179 > 65536)**

After looking for other newer tutorial, I found a message from the dialogflow-android github page which i conclude saying that the android sdk has been deprecated since October 2019 (which is after the tutorial was created). And from the dialogflow documentation page, I can't find any android sdk documentation.

Has the SDK been deprecated or there is another solution for this error?

Answer (score 2):

That error isn't related to deprecation, it just means you need to [enable Multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) in your app.

Comment: wow i feel silly, cause i've looked at that solution before but i thought i have different approach since im using different dependencies.. thanks